# multilabel classification with OneVsOneClassifier

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, text-classification

Is it possible one multilabel classification with OneVsOneClassifier?

I made the classification of OneVsRestClassifier follows:

```
lb = preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer()

Y = lb.fit_transform(y_train)

classifier = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer',CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf',TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf',OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel='linear')))])


classifier.fit(X_train,Y)
predicted = classifier.predict(X_test)
all_label = lb.inverse_transform(predicted)
print all_label
```

But I use OneVsOneClassifier returns an error indicating an excessive number of labels.